# Need to export full data set from query in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am running a query which has  total record count is around `31K` in redshift.
But each time, when I am running, the result is displaying the record count between `17K to 18K` and giving one error pop up like: `"The maximum size of result was reached. You can use UNLOAD commands instead."`
can anyone please help me how to export all the data from my query in redshift

Comment: When run a query in amazon redshift, it returns a maximum of **10,000** rows. If query returns more than this, you'll get an error. So, to export all the data from query, use the [UNLOAD](https://www.getcensus.com/blog/4-ways-to-export-csv-files-from-redshift) command, which allows you to export bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try below where I provided a solution to export all query results from Redshift to an S3 bucket using the UNLOAD command, overcoming the `limitations of direct query interfaces.`

```
   UNLOAD ('your_query_here')
    TO 's3://yourbucket/yourpath/'
    CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=your_access_key_id;aws_secret_access_key=your_secret_access_key'
    DELIMITER AS ','
    ALLOWOVERWRITE
    PARALLEL OFF;
```